# Why does Gnome 3 ~/.cache/gnome-control-center have weird permissions?

Tags: gnome3

When I do a `find` or `du` or something in `~/.cache` I get an error:

```
$ ls ~/.cache/gnome-control-center
ls: cannot open directory /home/user1/.cache/gnome-control-center: Permission denied
```

It has weird permissions, which prevents the owner from reading or navigating into the directory (but the user's group can, if that were shared):

```
$ ls -ld ~/.cache/gnome-control-center
d-w-r-xr-T. 2 user1 user1 4096 Sep 30 16:51 /home/user1/.cache/gnome-control-center
```

That starts to look like a dropbox - write-only - but it's inconsistently applied such that 'group' and 'other' see it read-only and not write-only. Say (in the case for older corporate environments) you have a default group of `user`, then (because denial takes precedence, and permissions are read left-to-right), anyone could read that directory *except* the owner. And yet, they can't because the parent `.cache` is only readable & navigable by the owner.

I confirmed [this happening to others](https://www.cialug.org/pipermail/cialug/2019-February/028066.html). I guess I'm asking two questions:

1. Is there a documented reason for this permissions tomfoolery?
2. What possible reason is there for locking out the owner from a directory stored in their own homedir?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug and fixed in GNOME 3.30, see [gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/49](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/49).

The issue is caused by an unsupported raw octal value `0700` for the permissions of the user directory which is wrongly converted to decimal `700`. To fix this, the value needs to be written as string value `'0700'` in `meson.build`.

Source: [github.com/GNOME/gnome-control-center/commit/37a6b940cb83d97b808da77f397e34100beb263f](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-control-center/commit/37a6b940cb83d97b808da77f397e34100beb263f)

> build: Fix `USER_DIR_MODE` value in config.h
>
> meson defines `USER_DIR_MODE` with a raw octal value to be used as
> the default permissions when creating the user's configuration
> directory.
>
> However, meson does not support raw octal values[0], so the define
> misses the initial `0` value. Due to this, the directory is created
> with wrong permissions.
>
> This has been changed to use the octal value as a string in meson,
> so the definition has the proper value.
>
> Fixes #49
>
> [0] [mesonbuild/meson#2047](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/2047)